How can convert CJK's character in utf8 format with vba?
It is simple to convert CJK's character in utf8 format with python:
print("你".encode("utf8"))
b'\xe4\xbd\xa0'

The character 你 (means you in English) ,whose utf8 encoding is \xe4\xbd\xa0,How can get the result with VBA?

Using ADODB.Stream in VBA to convert CJK characters to UTF-8.
Option Explicit
Sub ConvertCJKToUTF8()
    Dim cjkChar As String
    Dim utf8Bytes() As Byte
    Dim stream As Object
    ' The CJK character to convert
    ' cjkChar = "你"
    ' If user can't input CJK char in VBE
    cjkChar = ChrW(20320)
    ' Create ADODB.Stream object
    Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    ' Initialize the stream
    With stream
        .Type = 2 ' Text mode
        .Charset = "utf-8" ' Set the charset to UTF-8
        .Open
        .WriteText cjkChar
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 1 ' Binary mode
        utf8Bytes = .Read
        .Close
    End With
    ' Print the UTF-8 bytes to the Immediate Window (Ctrl + G)
    Debug.Print "UTF-8 Bytes:"
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(utf8Bytes) + 3 To UBound(utf8Bytes) ' skip header bytes
        Debug.Print "0x" & Hex(utf8Bytes(i))
    Next i
    Set stream = Nothing
End Sub


Output in Immediate Window:
UTF-8 Bytes:
0xE4
0xBD
0xA0


cjkChar = "你" - that is not going to work.

The code has been tested on M365. ChrW is only required if the user is unable to input CJK characters directly in the VBE.

Upvoted +1 .... The user can input 你   to a cell and run the code (Works on Excel 2010 - 64 Bit)
